# MediaPlayer.onPrepared() is not called

Tags: android

I use media player in service and activity with a button(play/stop stream).
I'm trying to do such a one thing:
start serice only once when activity starts, and than use UI part to operate with media player in service (start, stop streaming). I'm using for it Service Binder.
But when i click on button to start media player, it causes errors:

```
E/MediaPlayer: start called in state 1
E/MediaPlayer: error (-38, 0)
```

Than i added the flag `isPrepared` to `onPrepared()` and on play stream button click check the flag. Flag is always false.
It seems that `onPrepare()` is not called or smth like that. Why? What's wrong?

**UPDATED**
**Activity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

String url = "http://62.80.190.246:8000/ProstoRadiO128";
Button mPlayPauseButton;
boolean musicPlaying = false;
Intent serviceIntent;
MyService mService;
boolean mBound = false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    initViews();
    initListeners();
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    serviceIntent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
    serviceIntent.putExtra("url", url);
    bindService(serviceIntent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    startService(serviceIntent);
    musicPlaying = true;
    mPlayPauseButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pause);
    Log.d("", "mConnection: " + mConnection);
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (mBound) {
        unbindService(mConnection);
        mBound = false;
    }
}

private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
        MyService.MyServiceBinder binder = (MyService.MyServiceBinder) service;
        mService = binder.getService();
        mBound = true;
        Log.d("", "in onServiceConnected: mBound = " + mBound);
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
        mBound = false;
    }
};


private void initViews() {
    mPlayPauseButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_play_pause);
    mPlayPauseButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.play);
}

private void initListeners() {
    mPlayPauseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            playPauseClick();
        }
    });
}

private void playPauseClick() {
    if (musicPlaying == false) { //mBound &&
        Log.d("", "mBound: " + mBound);
        mService.startStream();
        mPlayPauseButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pause);
        musicPlaying = true;
    }
    else if (musicPlaying == true) { //!mBound
        mService.stopStream();
        mPlayPauseButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.play);
        musicPlaying = false;
    }
}
}
```

**UPDATED**
**Service:**

```
public class MyService extends Service implements MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener, MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener{

String TAG = "PlayerService__Log";
String url;
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
private final IBinder mBinder = new MyServiceBinder();
boolean isPrepared;

public class MyServiceBinder extends Binder {
    MyService getService() {
        return MyService.this;
    }
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return mBinder;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    Log.v(TAG, "Creating Service");
    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
    mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    Log.d(TAG, "onStartCommand");

    url = intent.getStringExtra("url");
    Log.d(TAG, "url: " + url);
    if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
        try {
            mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);
            mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d(TAG, e.getClass().getName() + " " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
    mp.start();
    Log.d(TAG, "media player prepared");
    isPrepared = true;
}

@Override
public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onCompletion");
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (mediaPlayer != null) {
        if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            mediaPlayer.stop();
        }
        mediaPlayer.release();
        mediaPlayer = null;
    }
}

public void startStream() {
    if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying() ) { //&& isPrepared == true
        mediaPlayer.start();
        Log.d(TAG, "media player started");
    }
    else {
        Log.d(TAG, "media player is not prepared");
        //isPrepared = false;
    }
}

public void stopStream() {
    if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
        mediaPlayer.stop();
        Log.d(TAG, "media player stoped");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Why this just after creating it? `mediaPlayer.reset();`

Comment: @weston, where this line is needed to be?

Comment: You shouldn't need it at all in this code. It's to clear the object back to state like it's just been created http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#reset()

Comment: @weston, i commented this line, but the problem is still not solved.

Comment: I didn't suggest that it would solve it. It's just a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @weston, so what could be the problem?

Comment: No idea, looks OK. I might at least try `mediaPlayer.prepare()` rather than `prepareAsync`. You have a service so I don't think it makes sense to require async preparing anyway.

Comment: @weston, nothing new happened. Flag `isPrepared` is still `false`.

Comment: Do you see the `"media player started"` in the log cat?

Comment: @weston, no, it seem's that `onPrepared()` is not called

Comment: @weston, in log cat i see only `"Creating Service"`

Comment: Well your `onStartCommand` isn't even being called then.

Comment: I think you are missing this call `startService(serviceIntent)`; Please read: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html as you will need to stop the service too.

Comment: @weston, i added `startService(serviceIntent)`. After this Service starts and when i click to `play_pause button` it's OK(media player stops), but when again click to start media player it causes `MediaPlayer: Error (-38,0)`. I updated code of activity and service

Comment: You can't start it after stopping. Look at the state diagram here and invalid transitions http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html You probably want to call `pause()` not stop.

Comment: @weston, ohh, finally this problem has been solved. thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to start the service. Call:

```
startService(serviceIntent);
```

Please read [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) as you will need to stop the service too.

and for pausing, rather than `stop`, call:

```
mediaPlayer.pause();
```

Familiarise yourself with the state diagram and invalid states in the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html).

Answer (score 1):

`onPrepared()` is called when the player is successfully prepared/initialised.
But as the Error is indicating, something goes wrong during this phase and (probably) therfore onPrepared never gets called.

You could try to override onError, to get notified like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer, int what, int why) {
    Log.e(TAG, "onError");
    setPlayerState(PlayerState.ERROR);
    if (MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_UNKNOWN == what) {
        Log.d(TAG, "MEDIA_ERROR_UNKNOWN");
        if (MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_IO == why) {
            Log.e(TAG, "MEDIA_ERROR_IO");
            if (this.playbackPosition > 0) { //we could play this video in the past, but cannot resume. start all over again.
                Log.e(TAG, "Probably we requested a content range, but server didn't support that. (responded with 200), restarting!");
                this.playbackPosition = 0;
                start(this.playbackPosition);
            } else {
                callbacks.onUnrecoverableError(what, why);
            }
        }
        if (MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_MALFORMED == why) {
            Log.e(TAG, "MEDIA_ERROR_MALFORMED");
            callbacks.onUnrecoverableError(what, why);
        }
        if (MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_UNSUPPORTED == why) {
            Log.e(TAG, "MEDIA_ERROR_UNSUPPORTED");
            callbacks.onUnrecoverableError(what, why);
        }
        if (MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_TIMED_OUT == why) {
            Log.e(TAG, "MEDIA_ERROR_TIMED_OUT");
            callbacks.onUnrecoverableError(what, why);
        }
    } else if (MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_SERVER_DIED == what) {
        Log.e(TAG, "MEDIA_ERROR_SERVER_DIED");
        callbacks.onUnrecoverableError(what, why);
    }
    return true;
}
```